# Is there a way to create a resource-only DLL using mingw compiler tools?

Tags: winapi, dll, mingw-w64

It is possible with MSVC to create a so-called [resource-only DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-a-resource-only-dll?view=msvc-170) which essentually is a DLL that contains no machine code, but only [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources). Is there a way to create a DLL only resource file using mingw? (If not possible, is it possible using open source tools?)

I know you can use `windres` to compile rc files into .res files. But the resources are appended with the compiler. but what if I have nothing to compile?

Comment: in what problem ? set /NOENTRY (link.exe) equivalent and not include any src code ?

Comment: @RbMm strange, ld seems to create an .exe file, instead of a dll one. Is it simply matter of renaming?

Comment: no, dll have special flag in `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` - `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` for link.exe need use option `/DLL`. sure mingwin also have some option for build dll

Comment: *"is it possible using open source tools?"* - That's an odd question to ask. Surely, you have a *problem* you need solved. It seems a rather random requirement to want to be able to see (but not ever actually wanting to read) the source code of any given tool that solves the issue at hand. What's up with that?

Comment: @llnspectable sure, they tend to work without asking for Administrative permissions, afaik, you cant get MSVC without admin permissions, mingw works without admin permissions. And since I am doing everything with mingw, I suppose mix and matching is not desirable, since I already chose to work with mingw

Comment: *"they tend to work without asking for Administrative permissions"* - I can't recall *cl.exe* or *link.exe* or *rc.exe* ever asking for administrative permissions, so that doesn't make sense. On the flip side, I also can't recall seeing a (meaningful) digital signature on an open source binary. Regardless, the [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) has a pretty complete specification. With that, it's near trivial to just write your own resource-only DLL "linker".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windres [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/windres.1.html) says you can compile resources to coff object format and link it:

> The normal use is for you to write an rc file, use windres to convert it to a COFF object file, and then link the COFF file into your application.

> If the input or output format is not specified, windres will guess based on the file name, or, for the input file, the file contents. A file with an extension of .rc will be treated as an rc file, a file with an extension of .res will be treated as a res file, and a file with an extension of .o or .exe will be treated as a coff file.

So, e.g. with `my.rc`:

```
1 BITMAP "Untitled.bmp"
```

You can build it into dll by invoking:

```
windres -i my.rc -o my.o
ld --dll -o my.dll my.o
```